# Android Studio IDE - how to change focused tab color

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gnome, color-scheme, android-studio-2.1

I realized my currently focused tab is hard to distinguish:

[image]

So my question is how to change **currently focused tab's color** (Either foreground or background will help) ? I search around in the settings but can't found.

My platform is android studio version 2.1, Linux Fedora 21, gnome 3.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your shown tabs are hard to distinguish because in Darcula theme, the test class background is unfortunatelly very hard to distinguish from non selected test tabs. You can see, that you can distinguish MainActivity.java just fine.

How to change color for tests is described in this question:

> [How to change the active tab header's color in IntelliJ 14.1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32181520/4560142)