# Intellij 2016.2.5 Darcula 16: perceptible highlight of currently active tab

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

I find it extremely difficult to spot the currently selected tab in Intellij, if using the Darcula theme. I've looked for a workaround and I was not able to find any solution besides disabling the "Use in Editor Tabs" checkbox in Settings->Appearance&Behavior->FileColors.

This issue has been reported by several other users (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32181520/4828060)), but I can't seem to solve it for the current version of Intellij/Darcula.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I appreciate all the answers I got so far, but unfortunately none really answers my question.

Comment: did u try material ??

Comment: I did not try the Material Theme yet. What I'm trying to say is that both answers are workarounds and not a direct solution to the exact problem I'm reporting. After I try your proposed workarounds more thoroughly, I may vote them up if I find that they are good workarounds, however they should not be marked as the correct answer simply because they do not answer the question, i.e. they do not enable a more efficient highlighting of the current tab in the Darcula theme.

Comment: No worries about voting. The thing is if we don't have a direct solution, we have to go with the best alternative. :)) on the other hand I think both the answers have solved your more basic problem. :))

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix is to use the single tab model, where you set the maximum open tabs to 1. You can use open-recent, open class, and the project explorer to navigate around your codebase. I switched to this model after seeing a colleague working this way last year and I'm enjoying it. It took me a few days to get used to it, but having the tool enforce the single tab approach helps because you are basically forced to work this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not quite the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Material Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006) plugin for intellij. It has a dark theme like Darcula and it would underline and highlight your current tab.

And if you think long term perspective, actually Engineer Dollery is correct. When you get more and more experience with intellij, you also feel that working with multiple tabs is really a time waste. Single tab mode is much efficient.

Because intellij provides plenty of navigation tools like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , you really don't need tabs. These shortcut keys make sure your finger tips remain on keyboard and save the time you have to deal with switching to touch pad/mouse and again to keyboard when you try to switch the tabs in multiple tabs mode. If you count this time saving for a week/month, actually its a huge amount. :))