# How to remove material theme (or reset to defaults) from IntelliJ / PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, pycharm, development-environment

I have installed Material Theme UI and it made my IDE blackish. Later I decided to remove and and removed plugin. Unfortunately, this didn't give default colors back, some parts of IDE, for example Project pane, remained blackish.

How ro recover?

How to remove material theme from IntelliJ / PyCharm?

Comment: Is your theme still set to this "material" option in `settings > appearance > theme`?

Comment: whoever developed this plugin, you're a morron

Comment: JetBrains Staff Reply
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009460540/comments/360002018140

Answer (score 110, accepted):

you can go to the Preferences->Plugins on the search bar, type Material UI
then press on the Uninstall button .

Comment: like a PyCharm*

Comment: Settings -> Plugin -> Installed

Comment: Not working in Android Studio on mac os. Status bar popups are still blue and some other things.

Comment: default InteliJ for life !!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't like the material UI at all and just removed.

Comment: Just adding if someone couldn't find the uninstall option. it is located at the top right three dots menu.

Answer (score 34):

You should:

1. Go to `Settings->Plugins` and remove Material UI plugin
2. Switch to Default theme in `Settings->Editor->Color Scheme`

If it does not help (it happened to me) and you still have some colors/fonts from removed Material UI - looks like Material UI theme override some default colors. You should then close Intellij, go to Intellij config folder (on Windows it is `C:/Users/<your username>/.IntellijIdeaXXXX.X/config`) and remove this `config` folder and restart Intellij. It should show you a dialog window to import settings from previous version or use defaults (like when you install Intellij and make the first start). After that everything will be switched to default colors/fonts.

Comment: Luckily I had a backup config from 2017 I could reimport into 2018 IntelliJ. The uninstall of Material UI theme leaves IntelliJ in a bad state. I could not change the font of the Project panel back without removing the config :-(

Comment: With last versions, when you remove plugin, program ask if you want to restart or not to apply changes.

Comment: In phpstorm version 2019.3 just remove the plugin then restart ide.

Comment: The path changed to C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdeaxxxx.x\colors. Delete all files there and you're editor is default again.

Answer (score 16):

From the [material-theme-jetbrains](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains#file-colors-stuck-after-uninstallation) repo:

> File Colors stuck after uninstallation The File Status Colors feature
>   is also a feature that sticks outside of the realm of the plugin as it
>   modifies the IDE itself. Therefore when uninstalling/disabling the
>   plugin the colors will stuck.
>
> If you want to reset to the default colors, open the Settings at
>   Version Control -> File Status Colors in 2017.3+. In previous
>   versions, you will need to go to the config directory and delete the
>   _@user_Darcula.icls color scheme manually.

Comment: Visiting Version Control > File Status Colors, clicking each category, then pressing Restore Defaults reverted Material's stubborn file colors for me in PyCharm 2018.3. Thank you, I found them bothersome :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, that indeed worked. These modified colours gave me headache :D

Answer (score 7):

None of these worked for me as an acceptable solution. So here is what I figured out:

1. Go to plugins, uninstall Material UI.
2. Ensure colour scheme is Default/Darcula.
3. Restart Idea.

At this point most changes were back to default, but some things like colour of current tab, error highlights, modified files etc were still not back to usual. So I followed the advice of deleting `config` and things returned to normal. But with this option *you lose everything*, even the installed plugins. And worst thing was, I was using a *settings repository* to sync settings, few minutes later the colours were back! So I did a diff with older config directory and then a `git log` revealed that these files are the culprits.

Delete these 4 files from this path: `.IntelliJIdea<version>/config/settingsRepository/repository/`

1. colors/_@user_Darcula.icls
2. colors/_@user_Default.icls
3. material_custom_theme. xml
4. material_theme.xml

Then do a `git commit` and `git push` to ensure these are synced to your repository. And finally theme was back to normal!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately whatever I was doing from the settings, I've couldn't get rid of that theme. So I uninstalled the program and reinstalled it again without material theme. Hope there will be better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with intellij 2018.3 go to settings->Type material then untick the material theme after that restart ide should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A tad brute force, but you could try and delete the theme directly.

Close IntelliJ
Go to: ..\JetBrains\themes
Delete Material UI
Open    IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Press `Command + , (comma)` (Shortcut to preferences) and search for material. Uninstall the material in plugins section.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall Material Theme UI plugin: Settings->Plugins
2. Delete colors from the config folder: C:\Users\User name\<.IdeaIC2018.2>\config\colors (don't remove the whole config folder because all the previous settings and tasks will be removed)
3. Delete material_theme file: C:\Users\User name\<.IdeaIC2018.2>\options\material_theme

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how to do it in PHPStorm 2020.2 and above:

Settings (Alt + Ctrl + S) -> Plugins -> Uncheck the MaterialUI.

After unchecking, you would then be able to see an option to uninstall from the dropdown arrow found next to the install button.

Answer (score 1):

> This works for me in 2023.

**Steps**
Go to File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Go to "Installed" tab --> Search "Material Theme UI" --> Click on settings icon --> Click on "Uninstall" --> Click "Yes" in the dialog box --> Restart the IDE

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot of the steps from intelliJ IDEA]

[image]

**Make sure to Restart the IDE**

Answer (score 0):

**2019 version** File > Settings (or alt + f7 on windows), search for material theme ui

Answer (score 0):

if you have the stupid accents persisting through uninstalling the plugin, deleting config files and so on the solution is under:

appearance and behavior > file colors > delete all of them

Answer (score 0):

Another 2019 version (worked in my case):

- open the settings editor (`File->Settings`)
- search for `Plugins` page
- inside the `Plugins` page, search for the Material UI plugin and uninstall it
- search for `Appearance & Behaviour->Appearance` page
- select the theme you prefer (IntelliJ or Darkula or High contrast). If your theme is already selected, chose another theme, apply the changes, than select back your preferred theme.
- close IntelliJ (or PyCharm/WebStorm/etc)
- open `.IntelliJIdea<version>/config` folder, usually it's in your home folder.
- remove the following files:

  - `material_theme.xml`
  - `colors/_@user_Darcula.icls` or `colors/_@user_Dafault.icls` (beware: you may loose custom configurations you may have done)

Done.