# Intellij - Change color of active tab / editor

Tags: intellij-idea

It is difficult to see which editor is active under intellij.

Is there a way to modify the color on active or inactive, rather than all under "default text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors ([JB doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-file-colors.html))
- Material Theme UI Plugin
- Active Tab Highlighter Plugin

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181520/how-to-change-the-active-tab-headers-color-in-intellij-14-1-4) for details.

Comment: This will only work for the actual tab. I was talking about the background color of the actual editor. The new tab highlighter helps but on a large monitor it is difficult to see where the mouse pointer or keyboard is active quickly.