# Changing Android Studio tab color for Unit Tests

Tags: android-studio, colors, tabs

I am aware [that is possible to change the tab colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787202/2684) in Android Studio, but I would like to know if anybody has found a way to change the tab colors for Unit Tests.

As you probably know, the Tabs for Unit Tests have a distinct color (greenish if you use the defaults I think); this is true for Android projects (not sure about others).

In settings, it's possible to alter Both the foreground, background, and underline of active and inactive tabs, but I found no mention of "tests". Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was really missing a setting. They are located in a different place: Appearance & Behavior -> File Colors.

[image: Android Studio Settings Appearance And Behavior File Colors screen]

This same color is used when you *search* within a project, so use with care. Also this only affects the **background** of the text, so it must play nice with the tab colors you set in your [normal tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787202/2684).